# macos System.PlatformNotSupportedException NamedPipeServer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a macbook air m1. I am developing a projects on Net Core. But i have a problem System.IO.Pipe.
[image: This Problems who I have]

How do I solve this problem ?
I develop this project with my team. My team have Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like you added a lot of totally unrelated tags here for some reason. I'm removing the others, please stay focus and don't tag those for giggles.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [PipeTransmissionMode.Message is not supported on *nix system](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24097).

You'll have to use the stream mode and define message boundary yourself (e.g. prefix the message with length), or use other protocols like UDP for communication.